# jitsi-videobridge.service: daemons using outdated libraries

Tags: debian, package-management, video, libraries, daemon

Ever since the installation of the Jitsi video conference software, when executing `needrestart`, a utility that checks which daemons need to be restarted after library upgrades (or each time new packages are installed), it informs that jitsi-videobridge deamon is using outdated libraries.

```
$ sudo needrestart

Daemons using outdated libraries 
Which services should be restarted?
[*] jitsi-videobridge.service   

Scanning processes...

Scanning candidates...Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...
 systemctl restart jitsi-videobridge.service

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
```

Any hints on how to handle this problem?

Possibly relevant information

```
uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

sudo apt-get install jitsi-videobridge 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jitsi-videobridge is already the newest version (1126-1).

jitsi --version 
Jitsi 2.10.5550

dpkg -l | grep needrestart
ii  needrestart                            3.4-5
```

Relevant part of the output of `needrestart`

```
sudo needrestart -r l -v
[main] eval /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf
[main] needrestart v3.4
[main] running in root mode
[Core] Using UI 'NeedRestart::UI::stdio'...
[main] systemd detected
[Core] #816 is a NeedRestart::Interp::Python
[Python] #816: source=/usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown
[Core] #827 is a NeedRestart::Interp::Python
[Python] #827: source=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server
[Core] #914 is a NeedRestart::Interp::Java
[main] #10490 uses deleted /tmp/jna-105622/jna4127640304239884617.tmp
[main] #10490 is not a child
[main] #10490 exe => /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
[Core] #10490 is a NeedRestart::Interp::Java
[Core] #10490 source is UNKNOWN
[main] #10490 is jitsi-videobridge.service
[uCode/Intel] available revision: 0x0021
[Kernel] Linux: kernel release 4.19.0-8-amd64, kernel version #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26)
[Kernel/Linux] /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-amd64 => 4.19.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) [4.19.0-8-amd64]*
[Kernel/Linux] /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 => 4.19.0-6-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) 
[4.19.0-6-amd64]
[Kernel/Linux] /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64 => 4.9.0-6-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) 
[4.9.0-6-amd64]
[Kernel/Linux] Expected linux version: 4.19.0-8-amd64

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

Services to be restarted:
 systemctl restart jitsi-videobridge.service

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
```

Concerning

```
[main] #10490 uses deleted /tmp/jna-105622/jna4127640304239884617.tmp
```

the filename changes after each restart, and indeed, the file gets deleted right after the start. It seems this is just a temp file, maybe this should be ignored?

```
cat /proc/10490/stat
10490 (java) S 1 10490 10490 0 -1 1077936384 265115 956 0 0 10475 4457 0 0 20 0 81 0 137315 7117078528 63057 18446744073709551615 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 16800975 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Use `sudo needrestart -v`  to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for the problem I added

```
qr(^/tmp/jna-),
```

to `$nrconf{blacklist_mappings}` in `/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf`.